# How to converge and diverge Nodes in Forest?

Tags: forest

I want to have a structure like this-
[image]

However, I could come up to  this-

[image]

I want "P", "Q", "R", "S" coming out from "A Concept", "B Concept", "C Concept". How can I do this? My code is as follows-

```
    \forestset{
  not a tree/.style={
    forked edges,
    for tree={
    grow'=east,
      edge+={thick, -Stealth},
      thick,
      draw=darkgray, thick, rounded corners, top color=gray!5, bottom color=gray!15, edge+={thick},
      font=\sffamily,
      align=c, 
      parent anchor=children,
      child anchor=parent,
      anchor=parent,
      l sep'+=10pt,
      fork sep'+=5pt,
      tier/.option=level
    },
    },
  }

\begin{forest}
  not a tree,
  [Instances
    [A\\ Concept]
    [B\\ Concepts]
    [C\\ Concepts]
    [[P
                [P1]
                [P2]
                [P3]
                [P4]
        ]
    [Q
        [Q1]
        [Q2]
            ]          
    [R
        [R1]
        [R2]
            ]
    [S
            ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Could you make your code compilable (i.e., provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389)) so that people are able to help you as best as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the `fork sep` and `l sep` at the `B` node and then `\draw` a line from the `A` node to the `C` node. If you set the `l sep` and `fork sep` for the tree, you can keep the spacing uniform.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
    for tree={
      grow'=east,
      edge={thick, -Stealth},
      thick,
      draw=darkgray, thick, rounded corners, top color=gray!5, bottom color=gray!15, edge+={thick},
      font=\sffamily,
      align=c,
      anchor=parent,
      l sep=10mm,
      fork sep=5mm,
      tier/.option=level
    }
[Instances
  [A\\ Concept, name=A]
  [B\\ Concept, l sep+=5mm, for children={fork sep+=5mm}
    [P
      [P1]
      [P2]
      [P3]
      [P4]
    ]
    [Q       [Q1]
       [Q2]
    ]          
    [R
       [R1]
       [R2]
    ]
    [S
]
  ]
  [C\\ Concept, name=C]
]
\draw[thick] (A.east)--++(.5,0)|-(C);  
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is more of a brute force solution rather then a way to connect nodes within the `forest` package but it works. I do not know how to get rid of the small circle, that is beyond my current knowledge of `tikz` and `forest`, hopefully someone else will be able to answer with a proper `forest` version.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.414mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}

\begin{document}

 \forestset{
 not a tree/.style={
    forked edges,
    for tree={
    grow'=east,
      edge+={thick, -Stealth},
      thick,
      draw=darkgray, thick, rounded corners, top color=gray!5, bottom color=gray!15, edge+={thick},
      font=\sffamily,
      align=c, 
      parent anchor=children,
      child anchor=parent,
      anchor=parent,
      l sep'+=10pt,
      fork sep'+=5pt,
      tier/.option=level
    },
    },
  }

\begin{forest}
  not a tree,
  [Instances
    [A\\ Concept,name=A]{\draw[-,thick] (A) -- ($(A)+(1.4,0)$);}
    [B\\ Concepts,name=B
            [[P
                [P1][P2][P3][P4]]
            [Q
                [Q1][Q2]]
            [R
                [R1][R2]]
        [S]
        ]
    ]
    [C\\ Concepts,name=C]{\draw[-,thick] (C) -- ($(C)+(1.4,0)$); \draw[-,thick] ($(C)+(1.4,0)$) -- ($(A)+(1.4,0)$);}
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```